# swift SFSafariViewControllerDelegate with iOS 9 target ask for iOS 8.1 compatibility

Tags: ios, swift

I want to use the safari view controller.
My Xcode project is targeted to iOS 9.
Surprisingly, when compiling my code, I get the following compilation error which suggest to make the safari controller iOS 8.1 compliant, though it was introduced in iOS 9!

```
Protocol 'SFSafariViewControllerDelegate' requires 'safariViewControllerDidFinish' to be available on iOS 8.1.0 and newer
```

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your fix (in Swift 2.0):

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *) 
extension YourlViewController: SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
  func safariViewControllerDidFinish(controller: SFSafariViewController){
    self.delegate?.onHtmlViewControlClosed(self)
  }
}
```

and set SFSafariViewController.delegate to YourViewController.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can mark the protocol method implementation as `@available(iOS 9.0, *)` directly in the class implementation.  You do not have to put it in an extension.

Answer (score -1):

The error message is telling you that you need to implement the `safariViewControllerDidFinish` method in your `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate`.  You are correct that `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate` was introduced in iOS 9.  **This is not asking for iOS 8.1 compatibility.**

Comment: You should read the error message more carefully @Cin316. I did implemented the method. It says that it need to be made available to 8.1 and newer.